# SQL Like to Contain (MS-SQL/TSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I will like to do something with SQL on my server.

Right now, we have a column containing "Message Content"

E.g

```
Message | Message Content 

1 | Hi :reaction: 

2 | Hello :banana: there 

3 | Hey :rocket: we are dope!
```

I want create a new column indicating "Emoji Used", if an emoji is used in message content then 1 else 0. All emoji stored in my database are short coded. They will always have ":", this is what I have tried, but obviously it wouldn't work.

The Like % operator does not work in this case. The operator "Contain" does not work in the server as well.

```
Select 
Case 
When M.Message_Content LIKE ':%:' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Emoji_Used
From Table [Message] M
```

Any advice SO?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc. . .) that you are using.

Comment: did u mean '%:%' ?

Comment: Yes. Don't ignore the large message that was displayed to you when you added the *sql* tag that recommended  that you add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax differs between the. You got that recommendation because the specific DBMS matters - ignoring it is wasting both your time (it slows getting an answer) and the time of people writing answers for you only to find out it doesn't work in your DBMS. (It's somewhat annoying when we go out of our way to say *Hey, you used this tag. You should also add this detail* and you simply ignore it and post without it.)

Comment: @KenWhite  sorry for not tagging it. T-SQL is what I am runing

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
Select 
Case 
When M.Message_Content LIKE '%:%:%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Emoji_Used
From Table [Message] M
```

Added `%` at the beginning and end.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it will find entries that have more than one colon but where these aren't emojis. So if someone wrote 'blah : blah : blah' it would find this as well.

Comment: that's a design problem.

Comment: What's your definition of emoji? I understood it was multiple letters surrounded by ":". Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi all. Yup it's a design problem. It will definitely include words that are embedded in ":". 

My definition of emoji for this use case is words embedded in ":". 


Select 
Case 
When M.Message_Content LIKE '%:%:%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Emoji_Used
From Table [Message] M 

I will try this and revert.

Comment: If you need "words", that is "letters", then you would need to use something like a regex to find matches. This solution is usually VERY database-sepcific. What is your database?

Comment: Have no control on the regex. TSQL

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can use its limited support for wildcarding:

```
Select (Case When M.Message_Content like '%:%:%' and
                  M.Message_Content not like '%:%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%:%' 
             then 1 else 0
        end) as Emoji_Used
From [Message] M ;
```

However, you could still get mismatches, if you have unusual uses of `:`.

EDIT:

SQL Server has really bad support for string processing.  This is possible to solve using a UDF or recursive CTE.  If you have a list of all valid emojis, the safest method is:

```
select m.*
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from emojis e
                          where m.message_content like '%:' + e.emoji_name + ':%'
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as Emoji_Used
from messages m;
```

Comment: Currently do not have an emoji table. Does that mean I need an emoji table?

Comment: @datagoondoo . . . Given that messages are free format, any simple logic using `like` in SQL Server is probably going to have false positives.